# Permanently set audiodg.exe priority and affiliation

Tags: windows-10

I am using Voicmeeter Potato but it causes crackling in the audio. I followed [this](https://youtu.be/71HrZfR_Fro) guide to remove it. Now I was wondering if I could permanently set the process priority of the audidg.exe process to high and the affiliation to my core 2.
Or can I just deactivate it?

Comment: Did you find any way to achieve it ? Im facing the same issue

Comment: Nope unfortunately not

Comment: I have found this soft where you can had permanent settings and it does the job : https://bitsum.com/
If it works for you I'll post it as an answer so you can mark it up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download this soft where you can add permanent settings : https://bitsum.com/